# Как реализовать такой эффект yandex карт у google карт?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, google-maps, карты

Вот [тут](http://php53.phpfarm.r52.ru/roman/polimerprom/ru/contacts/) есть карта, на ней реализовано переключение разных карт. 
Обратите внимание, что карта пролистывается до нужных координат или по другому, анимирует переключение координат. У меня реализовано через метод `panTo`, но он мгновенно переключается между точками. 
Как реализовать такой же эффект как в `google maps`?

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что это не фича яндекс карт. Т.к. если вы посмотрите ресурсы, в частности `javascript`, то обнаружите текст, связанный с якорями... А на ссылках обнаружите `href="#/nn"`, `href="#/nov"` и т.д. Думаю на этом как раз таки всё и завязано

Comment: Вы не поняли, не вкладки, а анимированное переключение координат на карте.

Comment: Я про них и говорю. Вы делали когда-нибудь якорную навигацию на сайте? Для плавного скролла вверх вниз используют, как правило, плагины. Тут тоже самое, только влево-вправо. НУ плюс манипуляция параметром `zoom`

Comment: Думаю, что никак. Разве что на основе гугл карт распиливать свою анимацию, стыренную из библиотеки Яндекса? Но легче просто взять Яндексовские карты)

Comment: Я что-то все ровно вас не пойму. Это вещи к карте не имеют никакого отношения. Вы работали с google картами? Делали переключение между координатами? Причем тут плагины для скролла?

Comment: Попробуйте посмотреть [вот сюда](http://s019.radikal.ru/i609/1511/54/0cec28416059.jpg) Возможно будет полезно

Comment: Мне нравятся больше гугл карты.
Значит столь тривиальная задача решается костылями, вроде этих?

Comment: Да неважно какая карта. Суть в том, что там используется. Я бы не сказал, что это супер тривиальная задача, а это костыли. Как раз такая задача не встречается часто. А это один из способов делать. И вроде как не плохой и не сложный. А так, конечно, всё, что не реализовано в апи, но нужное вам и реализованное вами  можно назвать костылями)

Answer (score 1):

```
var panPath = [];   // An array of points the current panning action will use
var panQueue = [];  // An array of subsequent panTo actions to take
var STEPS = 50;     // The number of steps that each panTo action will undergo

function panTo(newLat, newLng) {
  if (panPath.length > 0) {
    // We are already panning...queue this up for next move
    panQueue.push([newLat, newLng]);
  } else {
    // Lets compute the points we'll use
    panPath.push("LAZY SYNCRONIZED LOCK");  // make length non-zero - 'release' this before calling setTimeout
    var curLat = map.getCenter().lat();
    var curLng = map.getCenter().lng();
    var dLat = (newLat - curLat)/STEPS;
    var dLng = (newLng - curLng)/STEPS;

    for (var i=0; i < STEPS; i++) {
      panPath.push([curLat + dLat * i, curLng + dLng * i]);
    }
    panPath.push([newLat, newLng]);
    panPath.shift();      // LAZY SYNCRONIZED LOCK
    setTimeout(doPan, 20);
  }
}

function doPan() {
  var next = panPath.shift();
  if (next != null) {
    // Continue our current pan action
    map.panTo( new google.maps.LatLng(next[0], next[1]));
    setTimeout(doPan, 20 );
  } else {
    // We are finished with this pan - check if there are any queue'd up locations to pan to 
    var queued = panQueue.shift();
    if (queued != null) {
      panTo(queued[0], queued[1]);
    }
  }
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33339155/872294

Comment: Я примерно так же подумал, что реализовывать через setTimeout. Но разве нет нормального решения из коробки? Как например для анимирования маркеров

Comment: Google регулярно добавляет новые возможности в свои API. Можно ждать, но можно и использовать сторонние решения